# Java Jersey Link Header Parsing Error

Tags: java, hyperlink, jersey

I get a link parsing error when I try to create a Java Jersey Link object from a string, and the URI in the string has matrix params.

Here is an easy way to reproduce the exception:

```
String linkString = "<http://localhost:8085/myapp/testversions/files/big.jpg;version=1>; rel=\"source\"";
Link lnk = Link.valueOf(linkString);
```

The second statement raises a parsing error exception.

If I remove the matrix param, things work just fine:

```
String linkString = "<http://localhost:8085/myapp/testversions/files/big.jpg>; rel=\"source\"";
Link lnk = Link.valueOf(linkString);
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is [a bug in Jersey 2.4](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2168). The input is parsed using a very simple approach in [`org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.LinkProvider.initBuilder()`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.4/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/LinkProvider.java#L82):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value.trim(), "<>;=\"", true);
try {
  checkToken(st, "<");
  lb.uri(st.nextToken().trim());
  checkToken(st, ">");
  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    checkToken(st, ";");
    String n = st.nextToken().trim();
    checkToken(st, "=");
    checkToken(st, "\"");
    String v = st.nextToken();
    checkToken(st, "\"");
    lb.param(n, v);
  }
} catch (Throwable e) {
  lb = null;
}
```

This assumes that the tokens come in this order:

1. `<`
2. `>`
3. `;`
4. `=`
5. `"`
6. `"`

But your input produces these tokens:

1. `<`
2. `;`
3. `=`
4. `>`
5. `;`
6. `=`
7. `"`
8. `"`

So the assuptiom of Jersey that the second token is a `>` does not hold. `checkToken(st, ">")` throws an exception.

Of course matrix parameters must be valid. `Link.valueOf(String)` is supposed to implement [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988). The [current code at GitHub](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/LinkProvider.java#L86) seems to fix this problem.